# Recursive Angular 2 HTML Binding

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-template

Here's my problem, I want to include a button inside an HTML template, that links to an external website. But, when HTML is read, Google Chrome says :

```
WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
```

It seems that the Angular 2's innerHTML attribute doesn't allow 2 recursive HTML bindings.

Here's my code :

```
<ion-col width-80 innerHtml="{{ slide.content + '<p><button round full (click)=`' 
+ slide.button.url +'`>'+slide.button.text+'</button>' }}"></ion-col>
```

The (click) attribute is deleted, and only `(slide.button.text)` is displayed as single text.

Any solution ?

`slide` is like this :

```
{
    img: 'img/picture.png',
    content: `sometext`,
    button : {
        url: `http://www.foo.com`,
        text: `Site foo`
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467000/sanitize-input-in-angular2

Comment: I'm reading the comments, and it seems that it didn't fix my problem...

Comment: " seems that it didn't fix my problem" is hardly actionable ;-) What did you try? How did it not work? The message you get is from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizationService-class.html You need to tell Angular2 that you're sure the content is safe.

Comment: I tried to include the pipe that PierreDuc wrote, but the return type of `this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml` is SafeHtml.

And I don't know this object ^^

Check [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/SafeHtml-interface.html) for the doc of SafeHtml

Comment: Why do you need to know this object? Just pass it to `[innerHTML]="..."´

Comment: `innerHtml="{{ slide.content + '<p><button round full (click)=`' + slide.button.url +'`>'+slide.button.text+'</button>' | sanitizeHtml }}"`

Comment: That's what I have done ^^' And Chrome says that he can't find `sanitizeHtml`

Comment: The `(click)="..."` will be ignored by Angular and won't fire on click events.

Comment: Then you didn't add the pipe to `pipes: [SanitizeHtml]` of the `@Component()` decorator where you're using it.

Comment: Indeed. I forgot the pipes. But my `(click)="..."` is still ignored :/ It appears in my html code, but it doesn't look like a button anymore :

Comment: `<button round="" full="" (click)="http://www.foof.com" class="">Site GesCOF</button>`

Comment: That's what Chrome shows me when I inspect the element

Comment: As mentioned above adding `(click)="..."` or other Angular2 syntax using `[innerHTML]="..."` is pointless. Angular doesn't look at HTML added this way except sanitization (for security purposes).

Comment: So there is no way to do this ? Must I change my code structure ?

Comment: If you want to add dynamic content you can add components like demonstrated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll check that tomorrow :)

Comment: Hey wait. how would button redirect you to `foo.com`?

Comment: I use this : `goPage(page : string){
   window.location.href=page;
  }`. i forgot to paste it

Comment: I diverted the problem by adding an extra `div` tag in my HTML.

Comment: `<ion-col width-80>
              <div class="content" [innerHtml]="slide.content"></div>
              <br />
              <button outline danger (click)='goPage(slide.button.url)'>{{slide.button.text}}</button>
            </ion-col>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: I don't know `ion` thing so changed it to `HTML control`. changed `button` to `a (link)` control.

You can use `DomSanitizationService` as shown below,

working demo :  http://plnkr.co/edit/y2BXvIO8egNxJPmM3j43?p=preview

```
//our root app component
import {Component, Pipe} from '@angular/core'
import {DomSanitizationService} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',

  template: `
    <span [innerHTML]="myHTML"></span>
  `,
})

export class AppComponent {
  slide={
    img: 'img/picture.png',
    content: `sometext`,
    button : {
        url: `http://www.foo.com`,
        text: `Site foo`
    }
  };

  dangerousUrl='<p><a href='+`${this.slide.button.url}`+'>'+`${this.slide.button.text}`+'</a></p>';

  constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) {
       this.myHTML= sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.dangerousUrl);
  }
}
```