# Angular 2: Bind HTML content keeping javascript code

Tags: angular

I'm writing an Angular 2 application, that in some parts needs to render HTML that is loaded from an external API.

This works fine for pure, static HTML by using angulars [innerHTML] directive:

```
<div [innerHtml]="htmlToBeRendered"> </div>
```

The HTML that is beeing injected is loaded from an Content Management System. Sometimes this HTML needs to have some Javascript-Code for pure "UI" purposes (some simple DOM-Manipulation within the injected HTML). This will be vanilla JS and won't rely on some other frameworks like JQuery.

Is there a way to keep this JS code while binding it to the dom via angular? Currently all JS code is beeing removed by Angular.

I know that this is a security feature, but the API from where the HTML is loaded can be considered a "safe" source.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html) for this use-case. This service has a [`bypassSecurityTrustHtml`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html#!#bypassSecurityTrustHtml-anchor) method which is specifically designed for your problem:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: `<div [innerHtml]="htmlToBeRendered"> </div>`
})
export class TestComponent {

   public htmlToBeRendered: SafeHtml;

   constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer, public htmlService: SomeApi){}

   public getStaticHtml(): void {
      this.htmlService.getStaticHtml().subscribe((html: string) => {
        this.htmlToBeRendered = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
      });
   } 

}
```

For more info, you can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467000/sanitize-input-in-angular2/34467699#34467699) of me as well

Comment: This is working if I try to invoke a method on the window object like this:
 --- 
<button onclick="alert('hello')">Click me!</button>
 --- 

But if I try to invoke my own method that is declared within a script-tag it won't work:
 ---
<button onclick="doSomething()">Clicke me!</button>
<script>
    function doSomething(){
        alert("Hello!");
    }
</script>
 ---

Comment: @Simon i'm also having exactly same issue. Since you noticed it few months back, i guess you would have discovered the solution, please share. It will be a help.