# Using Angular 2 components in parsed markdown code

Tags: angular, markdown

I have a component html template:

```
<figure class="{{imgClass}}">
    <img src="{{imgUrl}}" class="img-responsive">
    <figcaption>
        {{legende}}
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

and a component ts:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'picture',
    templateUrl: 'image.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['image.component.sass']
})
export class ImageComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() name: string;
    @Input() container: string;
    @Input() legende: string;
    @Input() imgClass: string; //left or right for instance
    imgUrl: string;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.imgUrl = "http://.../api/containers/" + this.container + "/download/" + this.name;
    }

}
```

I just removed the API address for security (...), but you sure get the point. The idea is to have a component that loads the image from an API, and adds a caption and class. Calling my component from an html file somewhere else in the application works, with something like:

```
<picture name="test.jpg" container="test" legende="This is a caption..." imgClass="left"></picture>
```

Until now, no problem, the component is rendered correctly.

Now, I have some code that is loaded using a **Markdown Parser** (*marked*). To avoid Angular 2 sanitization, I used a method described there: [Sanitize input in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467000/sanitize-input-in-angular2/34467699). Here is a sample:

```
## This is a title
This is a sample paragraph

<picture name="img_bg_apidae5.png" container="test" legende="Ceci est une légende" imgClass="left"></picture>

This is another paragraph.
```

Marked translates the code to:

```
<h2>This is a title</h2>
<p>This is a sample paragraph</p>
<picture name="img_bg_apidae5.png" container="test" legende="Ceci est une légende" imgClass="left"></picture>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
```

The component is not rendered by Angular. BTW, if I create a component without any parameters, it does not work either. Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: Are you talking about the automatic escape mechanism?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know this mechanism. I have some markdown code which is translated to html, but my selectors aren't translated by angular2 after being "translated" from markdown (rendered would be a better term).

Comment: If your markdown parser is stripping your element, clarify which parser it is and tag with it. If there's literally the element outputted as text, it's the auto escape kicking in.

Comment: I added some markdown code and the translated html. My problem is two-fold: the parameters are stripped from the code and the component is not rendered. The element is not rendered as text, but as a picture tag, but not rendered by angular...

Comment: Make sure you set `sanitize` to false in the options of marked.

Comment: I tried. In fact, in marked, sanitize is by default set to false. It looks like Angular is sanitizing the code.

Comment: @Fabien as far as I know you cannot sanitize angular components, just regular html markup.