# Using Angular 2+ [innerHTML] to add html including style attributes

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I'm using Angular 2+ [innerHTML] input to insert HTML formatting including style tags.

In my template I have something like:

```
<span [innerHTML]="someVar"></span>
```

In my component, I have:

```
someVar = `<span style="background-color:#990000">test</span>`;
```

I get a warning:

```
WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
```

In the output, the inserted span in intact, minus the style attribute.

So I used a pipe from this post:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax)

It looks like:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SanitizeHtml implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(html): SafeHtml {
    // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
    // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
    // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
    // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
  }
}
```

This yields no difference than before, though I'm not sure I'm using that the right way...

How can I get Angular to retain my style attribute using innerHTML?

Comment: Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34467699/5468463

Comment: Thanks. What I had should have worked. I don't know why it didn't the first time... Anyhow, updated the pipe in my post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're nearly there. 
You just need to make sure that you are using your pipe for your HTML string.

Example pipe:

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core'; 
import {DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Pipe({
name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe {

constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(htmlString: string): any {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(htmlString);
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
<span [innerHTML]="someVar | safe"></span>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not recommended at all. You'll open yourself to XXS attacks

Answer (score 3):

Either you use this filter, or you do it in your code.

To apply the filter, you need to use it in your HTML like this :

```
<span [innerHTML]="someVar | safeStyle"></span>
```