# Custom styling of text substrings in dynamic Angular templates

Tags: css, angular

Is it possible to apply styles like bold / italic or both together in angular 6 by just having starting and ending point of the text while creating or after creating the components dynamically ? Right now I'm able to apply styles for the whole component but i wanted to apply style only for a particular text in the element and the length of the text will be from JSON.

[Please find stackblitz implementation here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-onwpn8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Actual result should apply the style to text based on the offset and length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1 - [Slice Pipe](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vjhxy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

If you want to add styling based on character positions within some text, rather than the overall length of some text, and you want to do this purely in your HTML template, you could achieve this with the [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe).

I've put an example of how this could be applied below and on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vjhxy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). The HTML markup is **horrible**, and line breaks must not be used in the code because these introduce unwanted spaces into the rendered text, but I believe it covers what you're asking for:

**For a single highlight:**

TS:

```
singleString = 'London Kings Cross Station';
highlightStart = 3;
highlightLength = 5;
```

HTML:

```
<ng-container>{{singleString | slice:0:highlightStart}}</ng-container>
<span class="styled_text">{{singleString | slice:highlightStart:highlightStart+highlightLength}}</span>
<ng-container>{{singleString | slice:highlightStart+highlightLength:singleString.length}}</ng-container>
```

**For multiple highlights:**

TS:

```
textStrings = ['London Kings Cross', 'Bristol Temple Meads'];
stylePositions = [[3,3],[15,3]]; // Start position and length of sections to be styled
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let textString of textStrings">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let stylePosition of stylePositions; index as i">
  <ng-container *ngIf="i==0">{{textString | slice:0:stylePositions[0][0]}}</ng-container><ng-container *ngIf="i!=0">{{textString | slice:stylePositions[i-1][0]+stylePositions[i-1][1]:stylePositions[i][0]}}</ng-container><span class="styled_text">{{textString | slice:stylePositions[i][0]:stylePositions[i][0]+stylePositions[i][1]}}</span><ng-container *ngIf="i==stylePositions.length-1">{{textString | slice:stylePositions[i][0]+stylePositions[i][1]:textString.length}}</ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.styled_text {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

**Method 2 - [Inner HTML](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8kt8vt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

A different approach would be to apply the same principle, but use a function to break your string into sections and then pass this to a div in your template using innerHTML - see below and this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8kt8vt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Please note that for this to work, you must also include a custom pipe to declare the HTML as safe for Angular to render with styling. This is also included in the Stackblitz, with more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46149691/2627160).

```
styleText(string){
    let styledText= '';
    for (let i = 0; i < this.stylePositions.length; i++) { 
        if(i==0){
            styledText+=string.substring(0, this.stylePositions[i][0]);
        } else {
            styledText+=string.substring(this.stylePositions[i-1][0]+this.stylePositions[i-1][1],this.stylePositions[i][0]);
        }

        styledText+='<span style="color:#ff0000">'+string.substring(this.stylePositions[i][0],this.stylePositions[i][0]+this.stylePositions[i][1])+'</span>';

        if(i==this.stylePositions.length-1){
        styledText+=string.substring(this.stylePositions[i][0]+this.stylePositions[i][1],string.length);
        }
    }
    return styledText;
}
```

Comment: Thats Perfect . This is what i was looking for . Thank you so much for the solutions .

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you should be able to achieve this with a conditional ngStyle statement, based on the length of the text string, or other criteria. E.g. apply bold and italic styling if your text string is longer than 20 characters:

```
<div [ngStyle]="textString.length > 20 && {'font-weight': 'bold', 'font-style': 'italic'}">{{textString}}</div>
```

Further information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46089536/2627160) and here is an example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u1n4m6).

Alternatively you can apply ngClass conditionally in the same way, and have your custom styling in your CSS file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i wanted to apply style based on the starting and ending point of the string. In this case i'm seeing the condition like if string has more than 20 characters you are applying style .

Comment: @matt-saunders's answer is perfectly fine. You just have to modify it a little bit to get wat you want. You can use a pipe instead of `textString.length`: `<div [ngStyle]="textString | myCustomPipe" >{{textString}}</div>`