# How to show custom html tags as plain text inside innerHtml

Tags: html, angular

I have a sort of strange use-case in Angular 2 where I have some content that contains regular html tags as well as custom html tags.  I want to render the regular html tags and show the custom html tags as plain text.  For example

`the <CUSTOM_TAG>boy</CUSTOM_TAG> went to the <b>store</b>`

should have `<CUSTOM_TAG>boy</CUSTOM_TAG>` appearing as plain text just as you see it above, however `<b>store</b>` should appear as **store** i.e. the bold tag is actually rendered.

When I try the usual way of inserting html i.e.

```
<div [innerHtml]="myHtml"></div>
```

I get a sanitization error because of the custom tag.  When I fix the sanitization error as was [done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467000/sanitize-input-in-angular2) it just strips out the custom tags which I also don't want.  Is showing the custom tags as plain text and rendering the regular html tags possible?

Comment: Do you know beforehand all the possible custom tags?

Comment: Did you try hard coding the special chars `&lt;b&gt;` ?

Comment: @ConnorsFan yes they will be angular2 variables

Comment: @mike no I never thought of that - it's worth a try

Comment: I was going to make the same suggestion as @mike. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwrera) is a stackblitz showing how you can do it.

Comment: @ConnorsFan that looks like what I'm trying to do - feel free to add it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the possible custom tags are known, you can encode them before passing the string to the `[innerHTML]` binding. The method `encodeCustomTags` in the following code snippet uses a regular expression to replace `<customTag>` with `&lt;customTag&gt;`:

```
private customTags = [
  "CUSTOM_TAG",
  "otherTag",
];

myHtml = this.encodeCustomTags("the <CUSTOM_TAG>boy</CUSTOM_TAG> went to the <b>store</b>");

private encodeCustomTags(html: string): string {
  let regex: RegExp;
  for (let tag of this.customTags) {
    regex = new RegExp(`<(/?)${tag}>`, "gi");
    html = html.replace(regex, `&lt;$1${tag}&gt;`)
  }
  return html;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwrera) for a demo.